# Inheritance in Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin and having problems with selecting the DOM.

for example, when I initialize the plugin (ex. $('#test').customplugin();

```
this.each(function() {
// Var
var $this = $(this);
$this.hide();
var thisOpts = $( this + ' option');
```

$this.hide(); works as expected, hiding the element #test.

however, when I try to get for example the li of #test,
nothing seems to work.

Can someone help me understand what "this" exactly is,
and why "thisOpts" won't target "#test option"?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `$this.find('option').hide()`? (More concisely `$('option',this).hide()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "this"? Because if it's not a string, you're trying to append " option" to an object.

Are you sure it shouldn't be the following?

```
var thisOpts = $("option",this); //find OPTION element(s) within This.
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that I was trying to append a DOM to a string. And + for the shortcut to find in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the DOM node that jquery previously matched.  It's a DIV, LI, SPAN, A, whatever.  In your example, `$this` becomes a jQuery set with ONE DOM node in it.  If you want to find something underneath it, `$(this).find('li')` will get you all the LI tags under whatever you currently have.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that I was trying to add a DOM to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( this + ' option');
```

this should be a string

or use

```
$this.find("option");
```